# CMake libifport.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, makefile, cmake, fortran90

I am trying to using cmake-gui to make a makefile to link fortran and python together. Everthing works fine when I was configuring and generating the makefile. But after I got the library and trying to use it in python. It turns out the problem that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "startDEMO.py", line 2, in <module>
import libdemo


ImportError: libifport.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am a new to the cmake,please took at my cmakelist. I want to create fortran as a subroutine and use python to do the operation.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.6)
PROJECT(Demo)
include(CMakeForceCompiler)
IF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER(icpc "Intel Cxx Compiler")
CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(icc "Intel C Compiler")
CMAKE_FORCE_Fortran_COMPILER(ifort "Intel Fortran Compiler")
ELSE()
CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER(icl.exe "Intel Cxx Compiler")
CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(icl.exe "Intel C Compiler")
CMAKE_FORCE_Fortran_COMPILER(ifort.exe "Intel Fortran Compiler")
ENDIF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
message(STATUS ${CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER})
message(STATUS ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER})
message(STATUS ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER})
enable_language( Fortran )

SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ".")
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH  ".")

SET(SRC_COMP_LIB
     hello.f90
     md.f90
     startDEMO.py
)

ADD_LIBRARY(demo SHARED ${SRC_COMP_LIB} )
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(demo PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE Fortran)
```

Anyone could help me to do something with the cmakelist?

Comment: it's not the problem with cmakelist?

Answer (score 2):

Did you do

```
source /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
```

(or ia32)

that should be always done when using Intel compilers?

Comment: Thanks!i add intel compiler but it turns out:  dynamic module does not define init function (initlibdemo) I think I didn't add f2py on the cmakelist. do you know how to link this two together?